# Advice on explaining this system observation analytically

Tags: dynamical-systems, control-theory, mathematical-modeling, nonlinear-system

I am playing around with an disturbance observer to estimate disturbance in a nonlinear system. (I had to screen snip the equations because the equation editor doesn't seem to work for me)

System prelims:

[image]

Basic estimator:

[image]

where the estimated disturbance is:

[image]

The basic estimator above is great for step or constant disturbances and has fast convergence, however when adding a ramp disturbance the estimator cant keep up and there is a delta.

Therefore the intermediate estimator is used:

Now the estimated disturbance is:

[image]

The intermediate one works well for step/constant and ramp disturbances and has good convergence. However when higher order disturbances are present such as sinusoidal disturbances it fails.

Therefore an advanced version is used to essentially integrate the remaining delta as many times as required, usually around 3 additional integrators works well:

[image]

The advanced one is the best version but comes at the cost of more complexity.
I have simulated this and I can see how it converges to different attacks, but I do not know how to analytically/mathematically describe this. I am an engineer and not amazing at higher level mathematics.

I know there are methods for linear system where there are poles and zeros that indicate if something will converge, but this will be a nonlinear system.

How can I describe this in a meaningful way mathematically?

Comment: The theory you are looking for is called the "Internal Model Principle". It is typically derived for controllers but it applies analogously for observers.

Comment: This looks like a linear systems analysis tool, any references for nonlinear version?

Comment: No, the internal model principle has been applied to nonlinear systems since its discovery. It is not limited to linear systems.

Comment: There seems to be some typos in your expressions. It should be the derivative of the estimate on the left-hand side. The expression of the estimator is also unclear (it would be better to write those expressions in latex or the like so that they could be easily corrected) unless you assume to measure the full-state $x$, which is a debatable assumption in many cases. Regarding the internal model principle, you can have a look at the papers https://doi.org/10.1146/annurev-control-042920-102205, https://arxiv.org/abs/q-bio/0309003, and https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?arnumber=10081206

Comment: @KBS maybe the original paper is wrong? https://ieeexplore-ieee-org.ezproxy-b.deakin.edu.au/document/5457987 either way it works as I typed it out. Thanks for your links I will go through them.

Comment: Link has a problem

Comment: Sorry, https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/5457987

Comment: Ok, then the expressions are correct in this framework and this is due to the fact that the  state is directly measured and used in the observer. However, the idea is the same as previously mentioned and is all about the internal model principle.